# Understanding Coding of Menu in Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, voyager

Can anyone guide me where is

> {{ menu('admin', '_json') }}

coming from in below code?

```
<admin-menu :items="{{ menu('admin', '_json') }}"></admin-menu>
```

Link of [Github](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.2/resources/views/dashboard/sidebar.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

It comes from Voyagers MenuBuilder (Laravel cms):

Link in your Laravel app (if you set PORT to 8000):
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/menus

Here are the docs:
https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/core-concepts/menus-and-menu-builder#menu-as-json

_json is for retrieving menu items in form of an array.